Comunicacion I2C
Intento comunicar un STM32 con una raspberry por medio de I2C, pero no consigo que funcione correctamnte. La idea es tener a las raspberry leyendo continuamente y que el micro solo mande algo cuando tenga algo que mandar. En el codigo tengo los mismos caracteres que se envian cada 3 segundos. Por alguna razon que no ocnsigo entender, no funciona. Si quito los condicionales en la dos funciones HAL_I2C_AddrCallback y HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback, el mensaje se manda continuamente y tampoco quiero eso.
void StartI2CTask(void *argument)
{
HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3);
HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(&hi2c3);
strcpy(tx_buff, "I2C\n");
for (;;)
{
    transmitir = true;
    osDelay(3000);
}
}
void HAL_I2C_AddrCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t TransferDirection, uint16_t AddrMatchCode) { 
if (TransferDirection == I2C_DIRECTION_TRANSMIT) { 
    HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT(hi2c, (uint8_t*)rx_buff, sizeof(rx_buff), I2C_NEXT_FRAME); 
} else { 
    if (transmitir)
    {
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_IT(hi2c, (uint8_t*)tx_buff, 5, I2C_FIRST_FRAME); 
        transmitir = false;
    }
    else
    {
        HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(&hi2c3);    
    }
} 
} 

void HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
if (transmitir)
{
    HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_IT(hi2c, (uint8_t*)tx_buff, 5, I2C_FIRST_FRAME); 
    transmitir = false;
}
else
{
    HAL_I2C_EnableListen_IT(&hi2c3);    
} 
}

Este es el script de lectura de la raspberry.
 import smbus
 import time

 bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
 direccion_i2c = 0x3a
 def leer_linea_i2c(direccion, longitud=32):
    try:
      datos = bus.read_i2c_block_data(direccion, 0, longitud)
      cadena = ''.join(chr(byte) for byte in datos if byte != 0)
      lineas = cadena.split('\n')
      return lineas[0] if lineas else None
    except IOError as e:
      print("Error al leer desde el dispositivo: {}".format(e))
      return None
    try:
      while True:
        linea = leer_linea_i2c(direccion_i2c)
        if linea:
          print("Linea leida: {}".format(linea))
        else:
          print("No hay datos disponibles.")
        time.sleep(1)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print("\nLectura interrumpida por el usuario.")
   finally:
      bus.close()


El código es de la Raspberry? Qué librerías usas?

No,es el codigo del micro. Utilizo las hal library propias de STM32.
